90s horror movie with a cannibal hunter
Here's what I remember from the movie 

A woman who is a journalist or a newspaper reporter covering something in the forest with her tape recorder in her GMC suburban.
She had an accident and the car broke and she got lost in the forest.
Then she found a cabin with a totem pole outside, this cabin turned out to be for a hunter with scary aggressive dogs or wolves.
He was friendly to her at first but then she found out that he is a cannibal hunter, so she tried to run a way from him, and he chased her while he counts 1 2 3 etc .
At the end the hunter dies I don't know how, and woman escapes and returns back to her husband.
I also remember the ending scene while she hugged her husband, a couple of girls playing and counting 1 2 3, which reminded her of the hunter's way of chasing her.



Additional Information:

It was an American movie
The woman while she roam around the forest, she saw a skeleton hanging from a tree.
I can't remember any of the actors, sorry
The movie was full of kissing scenes between the woman and her husband 'if that helps' :)



Here's what I remember about the woman from the movie:

She had a short haircut
Her eyes were brown, I think
She used to put a red lipstick
She is white
And I don't think that she is a very famous actress you know, I think she is one those early 90s actresses that appeared in a movie or two and that's it, maybe that's why this movie is hard to find.

I think the movie i called 'the hunter' or 'the hunting', I'm not sure, but the bad guy -the hunter- was obsessed about hunting and the Native American way to hunt hence the totem pole outside his cabin.
And no it's not an erotic thriller movie, there were only 3 or 4 kissing scenes with little nudity.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give?Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

The "kissing scenes" you mention: How graphic are we talking? If there are lot, featuring much nudity, you have an "erotic thriller", which was a staple of the '90s and usually starred Shannon Tweed. I don't see any obvious candidates for this in her oeuvre, however. More info about the female lead would help.

This is The Hunted from 1998 with Harry Hamlin and Madchen Amick.

Insurance investigator Samantha Clark goes deep into a Pacific Northwest forest to retrieve $12 million from a crashed airplane. While there she meets a mysterious mountain man who claims he can help her hunt down the money but instead he ends up hunting her.

It's all there. She has an SUV, talks to a tape recorder, has an accident, comes across the hunter who seems genial at first but then starts hunting her after counting to 5 to give her a 'head start'; There's a totem pole outside his cabin, he has an attack dog and he strings a corpse from a tree. The heroine survives and returns to her husband, but the hunter starts stalking her again in the city. In the end, she sees a couple of kids counting to 5 while playing jacks, which distresses her again. Though Hamlin and Amick were more famous in the 90s, they're still active. Here's the trailer.
